# Bootstrap Grid system with relative div top

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hi When I use Bootstrap's grid system (row and col-*-*) styles I get the following structure.
[image]

But What I want to have is the following structure where the top of second row div's should be relative to the first row div's. 
[image]

Is it possible anyway with CSS?

Comment: This is not possible with the current bootstrap grid system, This could be possible with bootstrap 4's flex based grid system. If you're using BS3, design this portion without bs grid system and use custom CSS or try plugins like http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: It's possible, instead of using 2 rows of 5 cols, you have to use 5 cols with 2 rows inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css but you have to change the grid structure and use `column-width` and `column-gap` . 
Check this **[Demo](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/yqrhw)**